# Как нажать кнопку по Enter в JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код,нужно, чтобы вот эта часть, начинающаяся с  `form.addEventListener("submit", (element) =>` работала и по нажатию на enter. На данный момент по нажатию на <kbd>Enter</kbd> получилось вывести сообщение, но как заставить работать форму, не пойму.

```js
(function() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (_) => {
    const form = document.querySelector(".form");
    const container = document.querySelector(".container-md");
    const inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input");
    inputs.forEach((field) => {
      field.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
        const cyrillicLetters = /^[а-яА-ЯЁё -]+$/i;
        if (cyrillicLetters.test(event.key) === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
      field.addEventListener("blur", (event) => {
        let correctedValue = field.value.trim();
        while (correctedValue.indexOf("-") === 0) {
          correctedValue = correctedValue.slice(1);
        }
        while (correctedValue.substring(correctedValue.length - 1) === "-") {
          correctedValue = correctedValue.slice(0, -1);
        }
        correctedValue = correctedValue.replace(/-+/g, "-");
        correctedValue = correctedValue.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        correctedValue = correctedValue.replace(/[a-z0-9]/gi, "");
        correctedValue =
          correctedValue.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
          correctedValue.substring(1, correctedValue.length).toLowerCase();
        field.value = correctedValue;
      });
    });


    form.addEventListener("submit", (element) => {
      element.preventDefault();
      let surname = form.querySelector('input[name="surname"]').value,
        name = form.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value,
        lastname = form.querySelector('input[name="lastname"]').value,
        fio = document.createElement("p");
      fio.textContent = `${surname} ${name} ${lastname}`;
      container.append(fio);
      document.querySelectorAll(".form input").forEach((field) => {
        field.value = "";
      });
    });
    form.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        //   event.preventDefault();
        console.log("вы нажали enter");
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="container-md">
  <form class="form">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="surname">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </div>
    <button id="button" type="submit" class="btn">Отправить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `event.preventDefault();` из события нажатия кнопки

Comment: У вас там очепятка `keydup`, должно быть `keyup`, а ещё попробуйте сделать `form.submit()`

Comment: исправила, не работает. нужно, чтобы по нажатию на enter вот это часть работала
```fio = document.createElement("p");
        fio.textContent = `${surname} ${name} ${lastname}`;
        container.append(fio);
        document.querySelectorAll(".form input").forEach((field) => {
          field.value = "";```
то есть добавлялся абзац с фио и очищалась форма

Comment: добавь минимальный пример разметки

Comment: добавила, форма, три инпута и кнопка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию нажатие `Enter` равносильно клику по первой кнопке с типом `submit`.

Проблема в приведенном коде заключается в обработчике

```
field.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
    const cyrillicLetters = /^[а-яА-ЯЁё -]+$/i;
    if (cyrillicLetters.test(event.key) === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

В котором блокируется стандартное поведение для **всех** клавиш кроме букв. Достаточно добавить исключение для `Enter`:

```js
(function() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (_) => {
    const form = document.querySelector(".form");
    const container = document.querySelector(".container-md");
    const inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input");
    inputs.forEach((field) => {
      field.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
        const cyrillicLetters = /^[а-яА-ЯЁё -]+$/i;

        if (cyrillicLetters.test(event.key) === false && event.key != 'Enter') {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
      field.addEventListener("blur", (event) => {
        let correctedValue = field.value.trim();
        while (correctedValue.indexOf("-") === 0) {
          correctedValue = correctedValue.slice(1);
        }
        while (correctedValue.substring(correctedValue.length - 1) === "-") {
          correctedValue = correctedValue.slice(0, -1);
        }
        correctedValue = correctedValue.replace(/-+/g, "-");
        correctedValue = correctedValue.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        correctedValue = correctedValue.replace(/[a-z0-9]/gi, "");
        correctedValue =
          correctedValue.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
          correctedValue.substring(1, correctedValue.length).toLowerCase();
        field.value = correctedValue;
      });
    });


    form.addEventListener("submit", (element) => {
      element.preventDefault();

      console.log('Submit');

      let surname = form.querySelector('input[name="surname"]').value,
        name = form.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value,
        lastname = form.querySelector('input[name="lastname"]').value,
        fio = document.createElement("p");
      fio.textContent = `${surname} ${name} ${lastname}`;
      container.append(fio);
      document.querySelectorAll(".form input").forEach((field) => {
        field.value = "";
      });
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="container-md">
  <form class="form">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="surname">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </div>
    <button id="button" type="submit" class="btn">Отправить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, наконец  - то заработало )

Answer (score -1):

#### Для начала

Есть аттрибут `autofocus` для интерактивных элементов (кнопка, текстовое поле, выпадающий список...) который при загрузке страницы автоматически фокусирует этот элемент. То есть после открытьи страницы при нажатии Enter он заработает.
Но тут минут в том, что, если взаимодействовать с другими элементами, то фокус пропадет.

#### Решение

Поэтому снизу вариант для общего случая:

```js
const formData = document.querySelector(`form#data`);

const buttonSender = document.querySelector(`button#sender`);
buttonSender.addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
  if (formData.checkValidity()) {
    window.alert(`Данные отправлены.`);
  }
});

window.addEventListener(`keydown`, (event) => {
  if (event.code == `Enter`) {
    event.preventDefault();
    buttonSender.click();
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="data">
  <input type="number" required min="1" max="10" placeholder="Вводите число от 1 до 10 включительно.">
  <button id="sender" type="submit">Отправить данные</button>
</form>
```